# reading image file from asset folder

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a image in my asset folder(welcome_image.jpg). and an using this code to read from asset.

```
Bitmap bit = null;
String url = "/assets/welcome_image.jpg";
bit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url);
```

but bit is null and throwing error as

```
03-26 16:42:15.303: D/Image exisits....(21547): Image url : /assets/welcome_image.jpg
03-26 16:44:39.853: E/BitmapFactory(21547): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /assets/welcome_image.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Please advise me how to achieve this.

Comment: try this
InputStream ims = getAssets().open("welcome_image.jpg");
            // load image as Drawable
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);

Answer (score 3):

You can use `AssetManager` to get the `InputStream` using its `open()` method and then use `decodeStream()` method of `BitmapFactory` to get the Bitmap.

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName)
{
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream istr = null;
    try {
        istr = assetManager.open(strName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: This definitely works.

Answer (score 1):

check this code

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            InputStream istr;
            try {
                istr = assetManager.open("ceo.jpg");
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                istr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out as below:

> ```
>  InputStream bitmap=null;
>   try {
>       bitmap=getAssets().open("welcome_image.jpg");
>      Bitmap bit=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmap);
>     img.setImageBitmap(bit);
>   } catch (IOException e) {
>       e.printStackTrace();
> } finally {
>    if(bitmap!=null)
>     bitmap.close();
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   InputStream bitmap=null;

  try {
bitmap=getAssets().open("welcome_image.jpg");
Bitmap bit=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmap);
img.setImageBitmap(bit);
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
if(bitmap!=null)
bitmap.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

    InputStream istr = assetManager.open(fileName);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following path:

```
Bitmap bit = null;
bit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file:///android_asset/welcome_image.jpg");
```

Comment: I tried it but getting response as null